# Unable to get properties of JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm returning JSON from a php file to a jQuery function, and am getting an object `output` with the properties `agt_id` and `agt_type`. With the webkit dev tools I can print see the object, expand it and see the properties. However, I get undefined when I try:

```
console.log(output.agt_id);
```

Here's what I'm seeing in my console with `console.log(output)`:

[image: Image from console]

Comment: Could you post the object structure you're seeing with the dev tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screen shot, it looks like your object is in an Array.  You can access the object at index `0` of the Array.

```
console.log(output[0].agt_id);
```

Comment: @Fluidbyte also, if you put `dataType: 'json'` in your original jQuery ajax call, jQuery should automatically parse the response JSON string into a javascript object for you.